# GraphViz's executables not found error in Anaconda?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-mining, decision-tree

I wrote the following code to build the decision tree, but I got the following error. can you help me?

[image]

```
       from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
       from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
       import pandas as pd
       import numpy as np
       from six import StringIO
       from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
       from sklearn import tree
       import pydot
       from IPython.display import Image
       import pydotplus
       import graphviz
       
       
       dot_data = StringIO()
       export_graphviz(decisionTree1, out_file =dot_data, filled=True,
                       rounded =True, special_characters=True)
       graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())
       Image(graph.create_png())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If you are using Linux try this in cmd: `sudo apt-get install graphviz`
- If using macOS, try this `brew install graphviz`
- i) If on windows install it by conda `conda install graphviz` and add path env variables `C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\Library\bin\graphviz`
- ii) Try to install it via `conda install python-graphviz`

Comment: I did this before but it didn't help

Comment: Which OS you're using?

Comment: ----windows----

Comment: Did you try `conda install python-graphviz`

Comment: yes, Is there another way to display a tree that does not need this library?

Comment: You can use `networkx` but you're able to visualize the tree only (not any info like graphviz in it)